# Importing files/modules the right way in Python

Tags: python

I am having some struggles with importing modules as my Python project grows larger.

I want my code to be executable on a different server as well, so I cannot use things like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/Users/Esmee/Documents/Folder_1/')
import File_1a
```

anymore. I have a structure in my files like in the picture below:
[image]

The problem is that *Main.py* is using *File_1a.py*, but *File_1a.py* imports *File_2a.py*.

If I use `import Folder_1.File_1a` in *Main.py* and `import File_2a.py` in *File_1a.py*, I get the error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timeSigBoost'**

But if I use `import Folder_2.File_2a` in *File_1a.py*, I get the error

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder_2'**

When I run *File_2a.py*. Does anyone know what is a nicer/more robust way to import modules?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: This has already been asked a lot of times, but I understand the struggle. This is the question I find more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Have you tried actually installed your package using cookiecutter? a "minimum" install should enable you to add your folder to your python package list and then importing like any other package.

Comment: Hi @manuhortet, thanks for your comment! It is still a bit of a struggle, but I'm a bit further now :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your `File_1a.py` file you simply want to use:

```
from ..Folder_2 import File_2a
```

Comment: This would work if running `File_1a.py` as the top-level script. But it would fail if importing and using `File_1a` from `main.py`, as the correct import would be `from Folder_2 import File_2a`.

Comment: How would it fails? If `main.py` imports `<Main folder>.Folder_1.File_1a`, which imports `File_2a` from `..Folder_2`, it effectively would imports from `<Main folder>.Folder_2` because the double dots indicated to step back two folder from `File_1a` (1 dot = `Folder_1`, 2 dots = `<Main folder>`). Unless I missed something obvious, I believe it should works as OP intends it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty `__init__.py` file in the folders.
Then `import Folder_2.File_2a` should work.

Comment: This won't help if OP runs `File_1a` directly at some point. The need to run individual files is implied in the question.